# Got error "The package system is broken " Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, dependencies

I need some help regarding below error. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and i am trying to install Ros melodic. I didn't successfully install all ROS packages and got this error also.

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

python-rosdep-modules: Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is installed
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~) but it is a virtual package
                       Depends: python-rospkg-modules (>= 1.1.10) but it is not installed
python-rosdistro-modules: Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is installed
                          Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~) but it is a virtual package
                          Depends: python-rospkg-modules but it is not installed
```